# Nasa Image download

Tags: bash, awk, web-scraping, sed, grep

I want to download image from Nasa with the following options.

1. Given a specific date, the script should be able to download the image posted on that date
2. Given a specific date, the script should be able to download the title, explanation text and credits
3. Given a specific date, the script should be able to download the title, explanation text and credits

Following is the code I tried but its not fully functional.

```bsh
GET_DESCRIPTION="yes"

PICTURES_DIR=~/Pictures

DESCRIPTION_DIR=~

function get_page {
    echo "Downloading page to find image"
    wget http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ --quiet -O /tmp/apod.html
    grep -m 1 jpg /tmp/apod.html | sed -e 's/<//' -e 's/>//' -e 's/.*=//' -e 's/"//g' -e 's/^/http:\/\/apod.nasa.gov\/apod\//' > /tmp/pic_url
}

function save_description {
    if [ ${GET_DESCRIPTION} == "yes" ]; then
        echo "Getting description from page"
        # Get description
        if [ -e $DESCRIPTION_DIR/description.txt ]; then
            rm $DESCRIPTION_DIR/description.txt
        fi

        if [ ! -e /tmp/apod.html ]; then
            get_page
        fi

        echo "Parsing description"
        sed -n '/<b> Explanation: <\/b>/,/<p> <center>/p' /tmp/apod.html |
        sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba' |
        grep -Ev 'Explanation:' |
        tr '\n' ' ' |
        sed 's/  /\n\n/g' |
        awk 'NF { print $0 "\n" }' |
        sed 's/^[ \t]*//' |
        sed 's/[ \t]*$//' > $DESCRIPTION_DIR/description.txt
    fi
}

TODAY=$(date +'%Y%m%d')

if [ ! -e ~/Pictures/${TODAY}_apod.jpg ]; then
    echo "We don't have the picture saved, save it"

    get_page

    PICURL=`/bin/cat /tmp/pic_url`

    echo  "Picture URL is: ${PICURL}"

    echo  "Downloading image"
    wget --quiet $PICURL -O $PICTURES_DIR/${TODAY}_apod.jpg

    echo "Setting image as wallpaper"
    gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename $PICTURES_DIR/${TODAY}_apod.jpg

    save_description

else
    get_page

    PICURL=`/bin/cat /tmp/pic_url`

    echo  "Picture URL is: ${PICURL}"

    SITEFILESIZE=$(wget --spider $PICURL 2>&1 | grep Length | awk '{print $2}')
    FILEFILESIZE=$(stat -c %s $PICTURES_DIR/${TODAY}_apod.jpg)

    if [ $SITEFILESIZE != $FILEFILESIZE ]; then
        echo "The picture has been updated, getting updated copy"
        rm $PICTURES_DIR/${TODAY}_apod.jpg


        PICURL=`/bin/cat /tmp/pic_url`

        echo  "Downloading image"
        wget --quiet $PICURL -O $PICTURES_DIR/${TODAY}_apod.jpg

        echo "Setting image as wallpaper"
       $PICTURES_DIR/${TODAY}_apod.jpg

        save_description
    else
        echo "Picture is the same, finishing up"
    fi
fi
```

Please I am very new to bash and I found the above code from GitHub. This is not my work. I can understand what's happening in the code but it's not doing what I want. Please help

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Once you have option 2 working, option 3 should be straightforward. But joking aside, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [intro pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with particular attention to the page on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You say this code isn't doing what you want? What is it doing, and what do you want it to do? Is it doing any part correctly? Is it doing any part incorrectly? Is it doing something extraneous, or not doing something important at all?

Comment: Also, what operating system are you using and what errors do you get when you run the script? PS: When I run the script on Mac 10.10 + macports, the line with gconftool-2 fails because I don't have gconftool-2, but the image download part works fine.

Comment: Thanks @webb for your reply. I am very new here and haven't had time to explore more on the page. My next post will be better. I  am using linux. I wanted to download image from Nasa on a specific given date but at the moment its downloading the current date.

Answer (score 0):

To modify your existing code to download a specific date, change:

```
TODAY=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
```

to:

```
TODAY=$1
```

and pass your date to your script by running your script like this:

```
./nasa.sh 20191031
```

The image will be saved in `~/Pictures`, and the description will be saved as `~/description.txt`. (`~` means your home directory.) You can change the image and description destination directories by changing these variable assignments at the top of the script:

```
PICTURES_DIR=~/Pictures
DESCRIPTION_DIR=~
```

PS: delete these lines about setting the image as your desktop wallpaper:

```
echo "Setting image as wallpaper"
gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename $PICTURES_DIR/${TODAY}_apod.jpg
```